# How to inherit DBT source documentation in the models

Tags: python, documentation, dbt

I have multiple DBT models that read from the same source database, and despite having written documentation (descriptions, tests, etc) for the source database, none of the columns descriptions carry over to the models.
I'd like the descriptions I wrote for each of the source columns to be copied to their respective columns in each model.
Is this possible?

Serving docs with descriptions written for the columns in the source table produced a properly documented source, but none of the documentation appeared on the models based on that source.
I was hoping I wouldn't have to make duplicate descriptions for the columns reused between multiple models

Comment: I am not sure if you can pass documentation defined in a model to models referencing the source. You can however use [docs block](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/collaborate/documentation#using-docs-blocks) to reuse any documentation you have.

Comment: See this discussion in the dbt-core repo: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/6527